# Null Pointer Exception widget button

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, setcontentview

I am trying to create navigation drawer. I have extended BaseActivity on my MainActivity class and SecondActivityClass.
While excecuting the error is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void   
android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference  
at com.example.navigationdrawer.BaseActivity.onPostCreate(BaseActivity.java:19)
```

I am not understanding, when I have initialized buttons before then what's causing the error.
`

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button inbox, address, logout;

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        inbox = (Button) findViewById(R.id.navigation_inbox);
        inbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(BaseActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
        });
        address = (Button) findViewById(R.id.navigation_address);
        address.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(BaseActivity.this, SecondActivity.class));
                finish();
        }
        });
        logout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.navigation_logout);

        logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(BaseActivity.this, "LoGOUT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: may be buttons are missing in the layout file you are using

Comment: i have added buttons, There are two seperate layouts for MainActivity and SecondActivity. I have setContentview in respective classes

Comment: and why you are initializing in `onPostCreate()`....? Maybe it´s better to use standard onCreate(). As the docs say: `it is intended for system classes to do final initialization after application code has run. `

Comment: I have changed and added in onCreate(), Now there are two errors, One referring to MainActivity.onCreate and other to Baseactivity.onCreate(). Errors are same, null pointer exception.